# Winding number of even and odd maps

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to prove that for

$h: S_1 → \mathbb C \setminus {\{0}\}$

if $h$ is an even map then it has an even winding number and if it's an odd map then it has an odd winding number and cannot be nullhomotopic.

I'm trying to use Cauchy's integral formula with no luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Here is geometric proof, although I am sure there is an analytic proof like you are looking for. Consider first an even function, then $h(1)=h(-1)$, so $h$ can be considered an the sum of two functions one on the upper half of the circle and the second on the lower half of the circle. These two functions have the same winding numbers, so $h$ has an even winding number.

Now consider the odd case, $h(-1)=-h(1)$, so add a semicircle arc from $h(-1)$ to $h(1)$. This gives one function, and now take the negative of this function, by the above argument, the sum of these two functions will have an even winding number, but the sum differs from $h$, by a circle about $0$, so the winding number of $h$ is odd.